# Converting census data to block groups with regard to their area

Tags: qgis, census

I have population data for census blocks and want to convert them to block groups. I know that block groups has an extra digits, but how it will be possible to break down census data between blocks weighted by their area!I have little experience with qgis and have to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The code for the 2010 Census Block contains information from higher level geographies. For instance, "060599800001002" the GEOID for some hotels/motels near Disneyland also contains information on the state (06 > California) the county (06 > 059 Orange County) the Census Tract (980000) and the Census Block Group within the tract (1). So, having information on Census Blocks you will be able to identify their Census Block Groups (060599800001).